# PouchDB inspector extension on chrome store gone (August 2017)

Tags: pouchdb

I had been working with pouchdb for 3 months now. Everything was working for the past 2 months until this august somehow the pouchdb inspector no longer display data on fauxton ui (that's what it was called i think) and is just showing the spinner icon. I decided to uninstall the plugin and to reinstall it again only to find that it was no longer available on the chrome store. I tried using another PC with the pouchDB still installed and it was also showing the same spinner icon(not displaying any data). I search the web looking for any news but found nothing. Even the link from https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html to download plugin was no longer working.Can someone actually verify this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A recent change in Chrome broke the extension and since it is unmaintained, it has been unpublished as an extension.  I'm taking this info from https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-chrome-extension/issues/17.  It is an open source project if anyone wants to pick it up.

What a negative answer, sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was thinking it might be an issue with my browser version, although I don't recall doing any update.I was hoping that rolling back to previous version of chrome might fix it, but alas it can't be because there is nowhere to download the extension anymore.

Comment: We're using an older (portable) version of Chrome dowloaded from here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

If you're up for it, you can download the git project from here: 
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-chrome-extension/ 
and build yourself a dev version of the extension using bash (read the "Building" section)

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not the same thing, but if you use WebSQL or IndexedDB, You can use normal developer tools provided by Chrome, going to Application/Storage and then look at data in your DB.
It is also explained in the official PouchDB documentation at https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Chrome changed deprecated some instruction used to get information from the local databases, this broke pouchdb, the suggestion from Google is implement that deprecated instructions by yourself, I´ll start working on that, I dont want to lose my work on puchDb